# Checking .nupkg files into Source Control - how to restore on build?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, projects-and-solutions, nuget-package-restore

Okay, I want to check my dependencies in to source control. Many people will argue against this for various reasons, however this is not what I am looking for in this question.

Please accept my requirements are that I want my dependencies in source control.

I am using NuGet packages so I have a `packages` folder in the root of my solution. Each folder within packages contains the `.nupkg` file along with the extracted contents of that package (binaries, xml, etc).

Since the `.nupkg` file is the zipped contents of the package, it makes no sense to me to check it in along with the unpacked contents. I just want to check in the `.nupkg` files and have them restored during the build process. This is where the problem lies. NuGet when restoring just checks for the presence of the `.nupkg` file and if found says that the package is already installed, it doesn't unpack it.

The only way I have found to unpack these files is to run `nuget.exe install` and specify the `packages.config` file of a specific project and use the option `-OutputDirectory {solutionDir}\packages`.

e.g.

`nuget.exe install {solutionDir}\{projectDir}\packages.config -OutputDirectory {solutionDir}\packages`

But this only works on a project level, not a solution level. So I will have to create a script to do this for every project in the solution.

I would love to rely on `nuget.exe restore MySolution.sln` but it detects the `.nupkg` files and doesn't unpack them.

Does anyone have an easier way to restore all NuGet packages for a solution when the `.nupkg` files are present however not unpacked?

Comment: I images you would have to write a script or console app to find all of the nupkg files and extract them.

Comment: @jrummell It just seems odd that NuGet restore doesn't do this. I feel like there's an option that I'm just missing that will do this.
It feels like because I want to check the dependencies into source control, that I have to add them twice, compressed in the nupkg file, as well as the uncompressed contents. Someone else must have come across this issue?

Comment: Well, nuget want really designed to be used that way. You could try reaching out to the nuget team and suggest this as a feature request.

Comment: Why has this been voted down?? This is a legitimate question. By default Visual Studio will stick all `packages` folder contents into source control except for the dlls. I wouldn't have thought this was an uncommon thing for people to come across and have to manually fix...

Comment: This little gem "NuGet when restoring just checks for the presence of the .nupkg file and if found says that the package is already installed, it doesn't unpack it." was useful to me so upvote for that part. :-)

Comment: If you are managing your nuget packages using the solution manager, then you will only have one packages folder for ALL of your projects in that solution.  Then you can use your command line to extract the images.

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to download nuget packages from internet just add them into a separate folder with name nuget_repo and register this  folder in nuget.config file as [a package source](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file#package-sources) . Check both nuget_repo folder and nuget.config in to source control together with your sources.